# Use IF conditional into where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where I want to use something like `IF` conditional into `WHERE` clause so I do something like:

```
 ...
 AND (@City = '%'
         OR [a].[City] LIKE(@City))
```

So I read this like : `IF @City = '%'`  just continue , if not execute `OR` clause `OR [a].[City] LIKE(@City)`

But when I run code results don't return values as I want. What am I doing wrong? am I reading this wrong?

Comment: it is a `OR` not a `IF .. ELSE`, so either one of the condition is `true`, it will be `true`

Comment: what is the value of input parameter @City? what is the sample data in the table and what you are expecting? These details will help someone to resolve your issue.

Comment: "but it doesn't return values as I want"... what does it return? Please [edit] your question to include sample data as ddl (create table) and dml (insert) statements, and desired results.

Comment: Are you sure you want to check for `= '%'` instead of a `LIKE`?

Comment: Note that simply using `[a][City] like @City` would provide the same results except when `[a][City] is NULL`. If `City` isn't nullable then drop the extra condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply do:

```
WHERE . . . AND
      [a].[City] LIKE @City
```

`%` is the wildcard for `LIKE`, so `CITY LIKE '%'` returns all non-NULL values of `CITY`.  This seems to be the intention of using `'%'` for selecting all cities.

Answer (score 0):

try like below:

```
...
 AND (@City = '%'
         OR [a].[City] LIKE('%'+ @City + '%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this on your where clause:
 WHERE @City = '%' OR [a].[City] LIKE '%' + @City + '%'